# When I try to sum by group using dplyr, why is dplyr ignoring my group?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I want to create a new column in the dataframe that sums by each group. The data frame is:

```
a<-as.numeric(c(1,2,4,2,2))
b<-c('G','A','A','C','F')
ab<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

This gives me the following dataset:

```
 ab
  a b
1 1 G
2 2 A
3 4 A
4 2 C
5 2 F
```

Now I want to take the sum of `a` by `b`.

```
ab<-ab %>% 
group_by(b) %>%
mutate(c=sum(as.numeric(a)))
```

My result was:

```
a     b     c 
<fct> <fct> <dbl>
1       G    10
2       A    10
4       A    10
2       C    10
2       F    10
```

As you can see, it completely ignored my grouping, and just summed `a` for the entire dataset. What I want is:

```
   a     b     c    
<fct> <fct> <dbl>
    1     G    1
    2     A    6
    4     A    6
    2     C    2
    2     F    2
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please add your session info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually made it more complicated than it needed to be.  No need for as.numeric when you create `a` and no need for `cbind` when you create `ab`

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- c(1, 2, 4, 2, 2) 
b <- c('G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'F')
ab <- data.frame(a, b)
str(ab)
#> 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ a: num  1 2 4 2 2
#>  $ b: chr  "G" "A" "A" "C" ...
ab <- ab %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(c = sum(a))
ab
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   b [4]
#>       a b         c
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 G         1
#> 2     2 A         6
#> 3     4 A         6
#> 4     2 C         2
#> 5     2 F         2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change `ab$a` to numeric. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

ab$a <- as.numeric(as.character(ab$a))
ab <- ab %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(c=sum(a))
```